# WIX Installing the required software with bootstrapper. Error "Extratction failed"

Tags: wix, bundle, bootstrapper

I trying instalation sql server from bootstrapper:

```
<ExePackage Id="SQL" Name="SqlServer2019" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes"
Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" 
InstallCommand="/ACTION=INSTALL /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=Password1234
/FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER"
SourceFile="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" DetectCondition="SqlStatus = &quot;true&quot;"/>
```

I checked where is problem without parameter "/QS" and on start I had to choose: "Directory For Extracted Files". When I run instalation from console line or run .exe the path:

> C:\Users\admin\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\

But if I run this from Bootstrapper path:

> C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\A0086387CD525BE62F4D64AF4654B2F4778BC98D\SqlServer2019\

What throw exception "Extratction failed". How repair this. I dont see I can set this path before instalation.

I would set this path, e.g. "C:\SqlServer2019"

I solved this problem by adding `/x:C:\SqlServer2019\` to InstallCommand.